# Django Logging Error in format : KeyError : ‘classname’

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, logging, django-rest-framework

Extra context cannot set with given log format which is defined in settings.py and I am using APIs are responding and even logs are generating in the log file if we remove `%(classname)s()] %(token)s %(router_macid)s  %(user_email)s  %(device_macid)s` From the format then it is working fine without and error, i am using django==2.1, djangorestframework==3.10.3

**Error**

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 994, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 840, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 580, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 549, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 391, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'classname'
Call stack:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 154, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 183, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 536, in log_request
    self.requestline, str(code), str(size))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 124, in log_message
    level(format, *args, extra=extra)
Message: '"%s" %s %s'
```

**settings.py**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'formatter': {
            'format' : '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)s:%(classname)s()] %(token)s %(router_macid)s  %(user_email)s  %(device_macid)s %(message)s',
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'

        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'my_django.log',
            'formatter': 'formatter'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'backend': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

**views.py**

```
import logging
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger('backend')

log_dict = {
    'classname': 'NA', 
    'router_macid':'NA',
    'token':'NA',
    'device_macid':'NA',
    'user_email':'NA'
}

class MyView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        extra_dict =  log_dict.copy()
        extra_dict['classname'] = self.__class__.__name__

        response=codes['200'].copy()
        response['message']= “Success”        
        log.info(" ".join(["Request received with =",str(request.data),"response=",str(response)]), extra= extra_dict)
        return Response(response)
```

Comment: `classname` is not a valid [LogRecord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) attribute.

Comment: @KlausD.thanks. I think you are talking about built-in formats. here I have defined custom format attrs which we can pass in info() with extra parameter context [link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output) and it is actually coming in the log file as well. if i remove `%(classname)s()] ` from `%(classname)s()] %(token)s %(router_macid)s  %(user_email)s  %(device_macid)s` then KeyError will be shown to 'token'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current logging configuration overrides the logging configuration for other libraries. Hence, the reason for the error (Refer to error traceback).

I recommend to only override the logging configuration for only your django project.

Make a separate formatter entry and leave out the "formatter" entry in its default state. You could also rename "formatter" entry to be specific to your project

```
'formatters': {
    'backend': {
        'format' : '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)s:%(classname)s()] %(token)s %(router_macid)s  %(user_email)s  %(device_macid)s %(message)s',
        'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
    },
},
```

Then make an entry to configure an handler just for your project which uses the configured formatter above. Don't override Django's logger. External libraries should configure their own logging.

```
'handlers': {
    'backend': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': 'my_django.log',
        'formatter': 'backend'
    },
},
```

Lastly configure a logger for your project that uses your handler.

```
'loggers': {
    'backend': {
        'handlers': ['backend'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': False,
    },
}
```

Remember to set [*propagate*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) to `False` to keep events from being passed to ancestor loggers.

Get your configured logger and use that in your project like you already do.

```
 log = logging.getLogger('backend')
```

Comment: I don't know what is the actual reason earlier I have 'django':{} block and i have the same format with it, it was working smoothly